# Microsoft Bot Framework, messaging endpoint error

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework

Can someone please please help me out. I have been trying for the last 2 weeks trying to deploy a bot to azure and interact with it...The deploying bit i got it covered. The only problem is the setting of the messaging endpoint. I've correctly appended `/api/messages` and made sure the url is https. Just as it's stated in the docs. So the resulting messaging endpoint is `https://gityangu.azurewebsites.net/api/messages`.

I however keep getting **NotFound The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.** Error. I cannot seem to find a solution to this

[image]

It works well debugging locally via emulator.

Comment: If you hit the endpoint directly (in a web browser) you get the same error, so there's something not right with your deployment.  When you say it works with the emulator, are you hitting it on localhost or on the deployed site?  Are you using the .Net or NodeJS version of the Bot Builder?

Comment: Could you share the header of your post controller?  Did you change its name or anything?

Comment: Could you login Kudu console site, or leverage App Service Editor to check whether there is a `web.config` file in your Web Apps to control the requests against your node.js application?

Comment: @Lars Its Node.js. I was hitting on the localhost but when i deploy it it spews up the errors.L et me check on the web.config

Comment: Feel free to share the deployment errors if you want me to take a look.

Comment: I found the error resulted in using, `/api/messages`, instead of `/API/messages`